# Time Sequence Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, time

If Thursday was the day after the day before yesterday five days ago, what is the least number of days ago when Sunday was three days before the day after tomorrow?

Please explain each step of your answer. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's simplify the puzzle step by step.

> If Thursday was the day after the day before yesterday five days ago, what is the least number of days ago when Sunday was three days before the day after tomorrow?

"The day after the day before" cancel each other out, and "three days before the day after tomorrow" is yesterday, so we can simplify to the following.

> If Thursday was yesterday five days ago, what is the least number of days ago when Sunday was yesterday?

Using simpler words for "a day when Thursday was yesterday" and "a day when Sunday was yesterday", we can simplify to the following.

> If Friday was five days ago, how many days ago was the most recent Monday?

Five days after Friday is Wednesday, so we can simplify to the following.

> On Wednesday, how many days ago was the most recent Monday?

To which the answer is clearly

> **2**

Comment: +1 Slightly less confusing than the question ;) Good work simplifying each part.

Comment: @rand al'thor - Thank you seems a small word now. You explained it perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

> Day after the day before yesterday is yesterday.
>  Now 5 days ago yesterday was Thursday.
>  5 days ago, it was Friday.
>  Today is Wednesday.
>  Now 3 days before the day after tomorrow is yesterday. 
>  Now it is on Monday that we say Yesterday was Sunday.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to puzzling.stackexchange! It is customary to add spoiler tags to answers in order not to spoil the fun for others. I have edited your post to add them so you can see how it's done. Happy puzzling!